# What's a data structure based on singly linked list such that both Enqueue and Dequeue take O(1)?

Tags: data-structures

How a structure works to implement the abstract data type file which is based on a simply linked list such that the ENQUEUE and DEQUEUE procedures are in O (1)?
Constraint: the structure implementing the queue must only be pointed by a single field (example: head, tail or number of elements, etc.)

My understanding is to circulate the singly linked list from tail to end.

But even in this case, there still need two pointers: head and tail to satisfy O(1).

However, the question requires the queue be pointed by only one single field.

Any idea or hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is doable with a circular linked list in which you point at the *tail*, so you can access the head in O(1) as `tail.next`.

```
class Node<T> {
  T value;
  Node<T> next;
  Node(T value, Node<T> next) { this.value = value; this.next = next; }
}
class Queue<T> {
  Node<T> tail = null;
  void enqueue(T t) {
    if (tail == null) {
      tail = new Node<T>(value, null);
      tail.next = tail;
    } else {
      Node<T> newTail = new Node<T>(value, tail.next);
      tail.next = newTail;
      tail = newTail;
    }
  }
  T dequeue() {
    if (tail == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node<T> head = tail.next;
    T result = head.value;
    if (head == tail) {
      tail = null;
    } else {
      tail.next = head.next;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```